# Significane of Priority Field in Security Policy in DPDK IPsec

Tags: dpdk

I am using DPDK v20.11.

I was looking into how the Security Policy (SP) was being added in the DPDK IPsec Gateway Application (Link: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/ipsec_secgw.html). There is a specified syntax under the heading **48.5.1.2 SP Rule Syntax**:
[SP Rule Syntax Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIokI.png)

There is a **priority** field and I was wondering that what would be the significance of having a priority in this case. Because if a certain set of parameters are matching 2 SPs, it would always be that the one with the highest priority would be selected thus in a way neglecting the 2nd policy always. Otherwise if there is even a single change in SP parameters, for example destination port, the priority would never come into play as then there would be only one SP valid for that packet.

I maybe overlooking a scenario where this would be useful and would be great if anyone can nudge in the right direction in this case.

Let me know if you need any clarification regarding the question and would be glad to help.

Comment: can you please clarify the question, are you asking `I have analyzed the ipsec-gw example and found that priority field is used to distinguish between 2 entries as wildcard best match. si this correct?` or `based on the documentation shared in the link, I am not clear what is the priority used for?`. So have you analyzed the code and making the query on priority field?

Comment: 2nd one, from the documentation link I am not exactly sure when would the priority field come into action and its usage. An example to display its scenario would also be great.

Comment: I humbly request you to check actual code and see if priority filed is used at all. I am sure you will understand further from there. Please let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: Ill give a look into it then.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, ill try to explain it in the below example:

| Sr.No | Src Address | Dst Address | Src Port | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | X | 1 |
| 2 | a | X | c | 2 |
| 3 | X | b | c | 3 |

**X:** Stands for Wild Card

**a, b, c:** Stand for a value under its column

If we get a packet:

**Src Addr:** a

**Dst Addr:** b

**Src Port:**  c

In this case if you would see the table, every row has 2 exact matching fields and 1 Wild card field, thus they are all a match but with equal number of wild cards inside it. In a way each of the policies match the required criteria of the packet. In this case the priority field would kick in, and the one with the lowest number would be selected as per the policy. Thus, in this case, row with Sr. No. 1 would be selected, which is also with the priority number 1.

Comment: did you check if the priority is added to the List or entry anywhere? because there are 2 implementations 1) ACL and 2) LPM. Is there a significance for the priority field in LPM?

Comment: @ameerusmanm were you able to check priroity for lpm implementation for same example?